# Find the node that has next value of current node value in Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I have BST of `BTNode<E>`'s each has double number and I have the following fields:

`BTNode <E> root`: a pointer to the root of the tree

`BTNode <E> current`: a pointer to the current node

I want to write a method Next() that make the current points to node that has next value of current node value

Here is what I have done so far:

```
public boolean Next()
    {
        // List<E> tempList = new ArrayList<E>();     // Creating new list (I defined this at the begining of the class)
        E tempValue = current.getElement();           // Gets the value of current element
        makeSortedList(root);               //
        E[] tempArray = (E[]) tempList.toArray();           // Convert the list to an array
        int index = Arrays.binarySearch(tempArray, tempValue);  // Find the position of current node value in the array
        if(index >= count) // count is no. of nodes in the tree
        {
             E targetValue = tempArray[index + 1];         // Store the target value in a temporary variable
             search(targetValue);                          // This method searches for the node that has targetValue and make that node as the current node
             return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    // This method takes the values of the tree and puts them in sorted list
    private void makeSortedList(BTNode<E> myNode)
    {
        if(myNode != null)
        {
            makeSortedList(myNode.getLeft());
            tempList.add(myNode.getElement());
            makeSortedList(myNode.getRight());
        }
    }
```

Could you help me write this method?

Comment: Your makeSortedList doing no sorting at all.

Comment: I tried to sort it as "tree sort technique" using inorder traversal

Comment: incompatible types - found java.lang.Object[] but expected E[]

Comment: simplest thing to try there is a basic cast - `(E[])tempList.toArray()`. That may give you what you need. Alternatively, use the `.toArray(new E[0])` method.

Comment: ok fixed that. Now I have an error at   int index = Collections.binarySearch(tempArray, tempValue);

Comment: It says: cannot find symbol - method binarySearch(E[], E);

Comment: ok, the errors are fixed but still the algorithm is wrong though

Comment: So...what does `search(E)` do? Traverse the list?

Comment: No. As I wrote above "This method searches for the node that has targetValue and make that node as the current node"

Comment: If you are just trying to update the current pointer to the next node in the list which has the next increasing value, why are you creating an entire list?  You can traverse the tree itself - this seems counterproductive and a waste of memory.  If your nodes have parent pointers as well as left and right pointers, the algorithm is rather trivial and no need to sort the entire list (a BST is already sorted, obviously.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check that the index returned by Arrays.binarySearch() is what you expect?
Also the elements should be sorted before calling it. And it is not clear from you code example how you handle the case when the value is not found within the array. Assuming it is always in the array why are you then retrieving the value @index+1?

Comment: I edited the code so it handles when the value is not in the array

Comment: and btw, when I checked the code the current is still same and doesn't change, maybe makeSortedList() doesn't really create a sorted list ?